# Flutter: class inheritance issue

Tags: flutter

possibly, you would be able to help me identify the issue with nested classes in Flutter.

AccountEditPage(uuid) -> AccountAddPage(title) -> AbstractPage(selectedMenu)
AccountEditPageState -> AccountAddPageState -> AbstractPageState

For some reasons from AccountEditPageState `widget.uuid` is not accessible, and fails with an error `The getter 'uuid' isn't defined for the type 'AccountAddPage'.`

Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class AccountEditPage extends AccountAddPage {
  String uuid;

  AccountEditPage({
    required this.uuid,
  }) : super();

  @override
  AccountEditPageState createState() => AccountEditPageState();
}

class AccountEditPageState extends AccountAddPageState<AccountEditPage> {
  String get uuid => widget.uuid; // ERROR: The getter 'uuid' isn't defined for the type 'AccountAddPage'.
}


class AccountAddPage extends AbstractPage {
  String? title;

  AccountAddPage({
    this.title,
  }) : super();

  @override
  AccountAddPageState createState() => AccountAddPageState();
}

class AccountAddPageState<T extends AccountAddPage> extends AbstractPageState<AccountAddPage> {
  String? get title => widget.title; // OK
}


abstract class AbstractPage<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  int selectedMenu = 0;

  AbstractPage() : super(key: UniqueKey());
}

abstract class AbstractPageState<T extends AbstractPage> extends State<T> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text('test');
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was not obvious, but the next:

```
(widget as AccountEditPage).uuid
```